# Convert Bootstrap Datepicker Date Using Angular Date filter

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have the following date being returned from my datepicker:

```
Date {Thu Oct 22 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)}
```

I am trying to use angularjs's $filter to format it the way i want but it does not appear to be working, is there a way around this?:

```
 $filter('date')(new Date($scope.form.date + ' ' + ticket.departure_time, "mediumDate"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up having to download and integrate [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/download/). I then did this to achieve what i wanted:

```
var ticket_date =  Date.parse($scope.form.date).toString('MMM dd, yyyy');
var ticket_time = Date.parse(ticket.departure_time).toString('hh:mm tt');
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the [date formatting strings](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) to convert the `Date` object to your desired format. [Here's](http://www.angulartutorial.net/2014/04/date-filtering-and-formatting-in.html) how to do that with Angular's $filter:

```
$filter('date')(new Date($scope.form.date), 'mediumDate');
```

Comment: It says "undefined NaN 0NaN" as the result when i try this.

Comment: Try `$filter('date')(new Date($scope.form.date), 'mediumDate')`

Comment: Modified my post, added time and tried what you just said but that didn't work too, same result as before.